# DeepZoom for WPF add items to map

Tags: wpf, deepzoom

I'm trying to figure out how I can place UIElements (Buttons, Rectangles) on a floorplan which is hosted in a zoomableCanvas as a MultiScaleImage.

The placed UIElements will change their backcolor and other properties dynamically.

Does anyone has an idea how to achieve this?

best regards

Comment: too general to give you a quick answer , maybe be more specific

Comment: Let's say I have a bunch of devices (up to 10000) which are represented by Buttons or Rectangles. If a device changes its state (e.g Off --> On), the backcolor of the Button should turn from gray to green. I would like to use the ZoomableCanvas from this Website [link](https://deepzoom.codeplex.com) because the maps will have 10000px and above and I want to reduce the memory footprint. ZoomableCanvas is a control which implements a Children.Add() Method but the children are tiles and I don't know how to add Buttons to this collection.

Comment: he clearly states "The control only supports Deep Zoom images (including sparse images), with no support for Deep Zoom Collections yet."  you can try to implement the changes yourself  and invest some R&D there is no magic solution

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used the pragmatic way and put a normal Canvas on top of the zoomable canvas as my Element Overlay. If I pan or zoom on the zoomable canvas, an event will be fired which refreshes the positions of the elements in the overlay. Works fine and uses less Brainpower.